# NIOSII with Remote System Update IP Core for Cyclone10LP does not execute

Tags: intel, fpga, intel-fpga

I am working on an update procedure for the Cyclone10LP FPGA with Quartus Prime 20.1.1.
The platform design is done the following.

[image: Platform Design]

The NIOSII Software Build tool for Eclipse Project is configured according to the .sopcinfo file. The NIOSII soft core works properly.

However, executing the Altera provided HAL function altera_remote_update_trigger_reconfig(...) does not trigger the Remote System Update (RSU) for reconfiguration. A verification of the RSU was also done with discrete logic, there it works properly.

My code looks like the following.

```
int main()
{
    altera_remote_update_state sp;
    sp.base = REMOTE_UPDATE_0_BASE;
    usleep(500000);
    altera_remote_update_trigger_reconfig(&sp, 1, 0x800000, 0);
    /* Event loop never exits. */
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea why the RSU does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify, if the right address offset is used in the altera_remote_update_regs.h according to the [Remote Update Intel FPGA IP User guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683695/18-0/register-map-31888.html).

I had to adapt the address offsets of the registers. (Hint: the RU_BOOT_ADDRESS register from the User guide is the ALTERA_RU_PAGE_SELECT_REG in the altera_remote_update_regs.h.) It seems that the board support generation does not adapt  all the needed parts.

Further details about the RSU on the basis of a Cyclone iV see: http://billauer.co.il/blog/2017/06/remote-update-intel-fpga-cyclone-iv/